# Trouble with templates in c++: "Expected primary expression before `>` token"

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code in a project I am doing for class. I have been having trouble with the print statement for hours, and I could not find what I needed on the internet.

Here is my templated class definition:

```
template <class T>
class oset {
    template <class U>
    class node { 
    .....
    };
    .....
public:
   template <class U>
    class iter {
        node<U> *pos;          // node _before_ the one with this->operator*
        // constructor is private:
        iter(node<U>* n) : pos(n) { }
    friend class oset<U>; 
    ....
    };
 private:
    iter<T> start;         // initialized in the constructors below
    iter<T> finish;        // initialized in the constructors below

 public:
    iter<T> begin() {
        return start;
    }
    iter<T> end() {
        return finish;
    }
....
};
```

Then the problem I'm having is in print:

```
template <class S>
void print(oset<S>& OS) {
    for (oset<S>::iter<S> i = OS.begin(); i != OS.end(); ++i) { 
        // ^-- error is on previous line
        cout << *i << " ";
   }
   cout << endl;
}
```

When I try to compile with g++ I get the following error message:

> oset.cc:276: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
>
> oset.cc:276: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope

The problem is in the commented line.  The '>' token giving problems is the one directly before the first `i`.  For some reason it does not like the `<S>`.  If i get rid of the `<S>` it tells me it expects a ';' before the `i`

I honestly have no idea what is causing the problem. I am getting very frustrated and any help would be highly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for (oset<S>::iter<S> i = OS.begin(); i != OS.end(); ++i) { //error this line
```

You've to use `typename` and `template` here:

```
for (typename oset<S>::template iter<S> i = OS.begin(); i != OS.end(); ++i)
```

Note that none of the following would work:

```
oset<S>::iter<S> i              //error
typename oset<S>::iter<S> i     //error
oset<S>::template iter<S> i     //error
```

Your situation is such that you've to use both keywords : `typename` as well as `template`:

```
typename oset<S>::template iter<S> i  //ok
```

Why you need both keywords here, is explained by @Johannes in this topic:

- [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

---

#### Few advices and improvements

- Make the iterator class a non-template. Use `T` wherever you're using `U` in its definition.
- Also rename the class from `iter` to `iterator`. Make it look like standard container/iterator, so that you could use it in agorithms defined in `<algorithm>`.

That is, your class should look like this:

```
class iterator {
    node<T> *pos;
    iterator(node<T>* n) : pos(n) { }
    friend class oset<T>; 
};
```

Then in `for` loop, you would only need `typename` as:

```
typename oset<S>::iterator i //ok
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your a life saver. might I ask why I need to do that?

Comment: +1 specially for the advice. It's really important that a code should be compatible with std library also.